# Как пофиксить слетающую авторизации после обновления страницы?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Есть приложение на React, с авторизацией и всеми делами. Почему-то вылетает авторизация при обновлении страницы.

Токен и таймаут сохраняю в localStorage. Туда при логине всё записывается корректно. 
Исходя из этого, резонно подозреваю что прокосячился где-то при проверке. Но не могу понять где.

Вот `authCheckState`, которая по идее должна проверять данные из `localStorage` и если всё в порядке, инициализировать `authSuccess` с нужным токеном.

```
export const authCheckState = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token === undefined) {
            dispatch(authLogout());
        } else {
            const expirationDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem('expirationDate'));
            if ( expirationDate <= new Date() ) {
                dispatch(authLogout());
            } else {
                dispatch(authSuccess(token));
                dispatch(checkAuthTimeout( (expirationDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот место, откуда она вызывается

```
class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onTryAutoSignup();
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Router>
            <CustomLayout {...this.props}>
              <BaseRouter />
            </CustomLayout>
          </Router>
        </div>
      );
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.token !== null
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onTryAutoSignup: () => dispatch(actions.authCheckState)
  }
}
```

Вот сама `authSuccess`

```
export const authSuccess = token => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS,
        token: token,
    }
}
```

Ожидаю, что после обновления у меня будет `AUTH_SUCCESS` и токен в `state`. Но в итоге ничего не происходит. Redux-dev-tools показывает `@@INIT` и пустой `state`.

Answer (score 1):

Дело было в передаче не вызова `authCheckState` (внутри `mapDispatchToProps`) а самой `authCheckState`

`mapDispatchToProps` должна выглядеть так:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onTryAutoSignup: () => dispatch(actions.authCheckState())
                                                          ^^^
  }
}
```